# Redirecting to page in Ionic after clicking on notificacion

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I am testing javebratt´s fitCoach example for push notifications using Ionic and Firebase.
javebratt/fitCoach

Push arrives well but when page redirection should occur I see the following error on the phone.

[Error seen on device when clicking on notification, page redirection should happen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu8qD.png)

[Line in app.component.ts where navCtrl error is trigered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEUwJ.png)

Code from app.component.ts is the following:

platform.ready().then(() => {

```
    fcm.onNotification().subscribe( data => {
      if(data.wasTapped){
        authUnsubscribe.unsubscribe();
        //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
        console.log( JSON.stringify(data) );
        this.navCtrl.setRoot('ClientDetailPage', { 'clientId': data.clientId});
      }else{
        //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.
        console.log( JSON.stringify(data) );
        this.navCtrl.push('ClientDetailPage', { 'clientId': data.clientId});
      }
    });


  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  statusBar.styleDefault();
  splashScreen.hide();
});
```

I cloned his repo from github, any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javebratt found the answer, a #myNav was missing from src/app/app.html

https://github.com/javebratt/fitCoach/commit/f89d5dcdd0080c38727f889c70517fd219b5b44a

Comment: Just as a sidenote, beware of changing Tokens when testing app in device. Log token to console to compare with Firebase and use fcm.onTokenRefresh.